# GCC multilib not installing in xubuntu laptop

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, xfce

I have been trying to install GCC multilib for -m32 option in my xubuntu laptop, but I cannot install because of `E: Package 'gcc-multilib' has no installation candidate` error.
I have tried `apt update && upgrade`, but it doesn't seems to work still. How can I install gcc multilib in xubuntu?

I am using Xubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did you check that this package exists at all in the repositories?

Comment: I doesn't says so.